# Manipulate Kubernetes' client-go PodList

Tags: go, kubernetes-go-client

I am poking around Kubernetes client-go and cannot get my mind around the proper way to manipulate the Pod struct...

I get a [PodList](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api#PodList) **pods** like this:

```
// creates the clientset
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
if err != nil {
    glog.Fatal(err)
}
// Get Pods
pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(meta_v1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

I can then get some of the values for each [Pod](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api#Pod) using a loop like

```
for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    fmt.Println(pod.GetName(), pod.Namespace)
}
```

But only from the **ObjectMeta struct**, which has some Getters (pod.GetName()), using *.Value* works too (pod.Namespace). I can't get my head around what's the proper way to access the data nested in [Spec PodSpec](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api#PodSpec) and [Status PodStatus](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api#PodStatus).

Maybe I am lacking some core Golang concepts... Can anybody enlight me, point me into some direction or provide me a generic example of the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, but instead of shamelessly remove this, I will provide an answer:

The Spec and Status struct I wanted to access are simply reachable using something like `pod.Spec.NodeName` or `pod.Status.StartTime`...

If somebody can provide a more elaborated answer to complement this, please do.